# Are Programming Languages the same everywhere?

Tags: java

Now I've heard the expression maths is the language if the universe; and most languages are based on maths.

But today i got into a heated discussion with my head of department over whether a bachelors degree in Ireland is the same as in America. The result was inconclusive. His main reason was that languages aren't the same everywhere!

This is news to me.

I know some terminologies are different.

Such as in America, I think they call classes adult and child.

Here, we call them super and sub.

But are languages really that different worldwide?

http://neosmart.net/blog/2006/and-we-thought-java-was-the-same-everywhere/

Comment: how about the people that vote explain why they think this isnt a valid question instad of hitting and running.

im a student for christ's sake!
im supposed too ask questions. i like too learn.

Comment: This question exists in a very gray area. It's very much about programming history and development.

Comment: I think it is a valid question. I've always wondered if languages were different in foreign languages, since most of the constructs (for,while,if,else, etc.) are based on english words.

Comment: Little clarification: it's parent-child, not adult-child. An adult class would seem like it's related to porn ;-)

Comment: yeah it is a common behaviour on stackoverflow...

Comment: This is not really a discussion forum, there are places to go to have long discussions.  SO is for asking questions that are specific that tend to have a right answer and can be answered quickly.  For your question it could devolve into arguments about which education system is better for example.

Comment: it seems like a simple yes or no question too me. its not one that shoudl have an opinion based arguement.

what people dont sem too understand is that i dont know these things! 

and the internet as massive as it is seems too be restricted too yahoo answers and this.

are there any programming discussion forunms you know of you can share?

even so. i wasnt aware this was a personal question for some.

hence why i asked it

Comment: The languages, technologies and techniques are the same everywhere. The qualifications differ but are broadly similar. It's like the difference between a degree from MIT and one from the community college in @sscrack U.S.A, you're better off with a degree from MIT. In Ireland we're told that all things being equal our courses are better/harder than those in the UK, which are better/harder than those in the U.S. (I'm pretty sure this is true for second-level / high-school qualifications). At that, a degree from MIT is more valuable than one from DCU or UCD (Irelands two foremost Universities).

Comment: Possibly if you tidied up the grammar and the structure of your question it would have been viewed better. I have read it twice and I'm still unsure of exactly what you want to know.

Comment: .....im not exaclty sure how too make it simpler.

are programming languages the same everywhere is what i wanted too know.
i have my answer anyway.

(forgive the grammar, im dyslexic)

Comment: I live in the United States, and have for almost all of my life.  For the record, I tend to refer to superclasses and subclasses, so I don't think that's a regionalism.  For the record, my primary language of choice is python, which might have some impact on that.

Comment: Programming languages are the same everywhere. Different people (and peoples) may have different preferences, but the languages are normally defined absolutely and not affected by the locale. There are some obscure cases where languages tried to be locale-aware and English keywords could be substituted by local equivalents and some languages are not based on English keywords (some even lack any keywords-as-such at all), but these are exceptions to the rule.

Comment: The way people think about programming, i.e. the paradigms, are probably more related to the programming languages at hand, than the nationalities, but especially in information theory the jargon may be very different, even across different universities in the same country. The underlying theory may be the same, though, just expressed differently -- and this is probably where natural language plays the most important rule.

Comment: Just as specialists in distributed computing may think of "transparency" as implementation hiding while low-level library hackers may think of it as exposing all the dirty details, sometimes synonyms or even the same words may be used to mean completely different things by different people. Also, often the English jargon may be substituted or replaced by a native language equivalent. This is mostly a one-to-one mapping, but sometimes the analogies might not work in different cultures and different paradigms may arise.

Comment: Obviously universities may differ in what their degrees actually represent in terms of acquired knowledge and skills and this varies even more across countries and continents (especially in Europe, which isn't as nicely homogenous as the US), but this has more to do with the systems at hand (i.e. the structural and historical differences between university cultures).

Comment: Now, what the article on Java is actually about is something completely altogether. This is more like different compilers having different interpretations and translating code differently. Often this isn't a problem because there is one authority on the language's use and the specs are definitive enough not to allow for any ambiguity. As any web developer can tell you, though, this is obviously not the case with HTML, CSS (not programming languages, but code languages nevertheless) and even JavaScript, where interpretation varies greatly from user agent to user agent.

Comment: With Java there is one authority (Sun) that also maintains the most popular bytecode compiler and virtual machine. However there are still many competitors for various reasons and these may not always behave identically. This isn't normally a problem when the resulting bytecode at least does the same thing, but it can easily become problematic when the semantics aren't as compatible.

Comment: So, yes, the languages are the same, but the interpretation may differ greatly. Add to that the problem of frameworks and system libraries and you know why, for example, different code is necessary for the same program to run on different operating systems, or for the same document to be passed to different applications. With interpreted languages or interpreted bytecode, these differences may be hidden by the virtual machine or interpreter (transparent, in the distributed computing sense), they are still there and the virtual machines or interpreters may differ in their behaviour.

Comment: why was this closed? how is it not a real question? can most of these oh so loving idol programmers not get a stiffy if a question doesnt have code. christ this is pathetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, you seem to be asking two different question: are degrees the same everywhere, and are programming languages the same everywhere?

Concerning the first question, degrees are definitely NOT the same everywhere. In the US especially, degrees vary widely in the types of courses and difficulty depending on the University. There is no country-wide consensus on what a degree's curriculum should be. It is up to the school districts to decide. This is in contrast to France for example, where the curriculum is determined by the government and each school has the exact same one. There are some differences in the quality of education from one school to the next, but not in the curriculum.

Concerning the second question, there are no differences with the actual programming languages. The keywords are the same. However, the tools will vary. Either because they are in a different locale, or because they are different altogether (since some don't necessarily support a given locale, especially third-party libraries, etc.). But the language itself is not the most important. Communication with fellow programmers and clients, understanding the business logic inherent to the market you are developing for are much more likely to have an impact that possible differences in the locale used for the programming tools.

Just my two cents worth.

Comment: well your two cents is exactly what i needed too hear.

i dont even care if you downvoted the question. that was brilliant. i wasnt really asking about degrees. but thats a helper. your answer was straight, clear and all i needed rather than confusion which i seem too be causing.

Comment: Actually, that isn't quite correct. There are univeristy degree accreditation programs. They do indeed set standards. This is why you can count on "CS101" in any decent CS program being a Data Structures course. See http://www.schoolsintheusa.com/ComputerScienceAccreditation.cfm for more info

Comment: sounds like the degree question can be answered with that old binary saying. there are 10 types of people int he world. those that can program, and those that cant

Comment: @OVERTONE: I didn't downvote your question, why would you think that?

Comment: i just meant im gratefull. its the most sensable answer ive heard all day.

Comment: @T.E.D: yes, there are programs such as this. And I never said there were no standards. But this is not government-related, and as such there is no legal binding to it. You really can't dispute that the course content and quality are massively different between MIT and ShelbyVille University. This large difference between universities is much less present in France, for example.

Answer (score 2):

I've always found the terminology to be language / platform specific, as opposed to the locale in which they are used... For example, VB folks will often talk about a function, and C++ folks will often call it a Method...

I certainly don't see the locale as being likely to have that much of an impact on the terms in use - software development is a techincal area with it's own well established community on the internet - and in practice at least I think THAT'S the locale that matters...

Martin.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure if this will help, but I can converse with Chinese programmers when we communicate, "in code," even though we may not speak a word of each other's language.  As long as standards such as a notation system and an understanding of computer science are maintained, human language is a non-issue.

Answer (score 1):

A bachelors degree in Europe is not the same as in America, due some part to the [Bologna Process.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bologna_process)

Relating to how languages are used and discussed, then this differs very much from country to country. And is very very hard to answer perfectly.

Comment: ok so he was right about the unimportant part. 

are they all the same everywhere?

Comment: They are trying to make a degree similar in every European country.

Comment: would make sense if they were worldwide.

too much division in the world in my eyes

Comment: Well the European union can only suggest items to countries outside the EU, but not enforce.

Answer (score 0):

One reason why I was inclined to downvote your question (though in fact I haven't) is that to my eyes it is not well expreessed: you seem to be switching between three different concepts:

1. Human languages as they are spoken
2. The content of Bachelor Degrees
3. Programming languages

Self evidently human languages are not the same everywhere, so that's not an interesting question. Hmmm, except that Wittgenstein had some ideas of a core of "sameness" across all languages, so in fact it's a very deep question ... but not a programming one, so I'll set that to one side.

Bachelor Degrees, even in the same subject, vary markedly. MIT and Oxford have different standards from my old alma mater, where I learned to program, Nottingham College of Education.

As for programming languages:

Any given language has some kind of spec, perhaps standard and formal, perhaps de facto. I know of no major language that has a fundamentally different varient in its syntax for different geographies. If my C code compiles against ANSI standard X here in the UK, it will do so in the USA.

Individal programmers may choose variable names in their own language (and no doubt speakers of specialised languages whose "alphabet" includes the { character have their own challenges) but the formal language definition is the same.

If we look at various OO languages, even those not of C lineage we can see some fundamental similarities, despite syntactic differences. So it is quite likely that there would be some recognisable features across the universe, but the sheer plethora of languages on Earth makes me thing that our alien friends have plenty of scope for something new and exotic.

Now, more interestingly, would we recognise alien Music?

Comment: im really targeting programming languages here.

bachelors degrees was just too explain how the topic came up.

ive seen some samples of spanish java. and i think i have my answer

Comment: I think what he was getting at is a concern that his degree won't translate "across the pond", simply because we use different words for computer-related jargon.

Comment: "across the pond"?

im guessing that was a crack at my nationality.
sorry too say its the first time ive heard it.

Comment: I wouldn't read it as a crack at nationality, in fact it's more an expression of brotherhood. A pond is small, USA and UK are close and friendly neighbours, divided by that Atalantic "pond", and the English language.

Comment: And as for terminology, we don't need to be in different countries to fail to agree on that. If the concepts are well understood it's little effort to learn new terms.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard lots of tales of folks who were Doctors or other kinds of degreed professionals comming over to this country (USA) and having to drive Taxis to make a living.

The thing is, any cheap scammer can create a "University" here and start handing out diplomas. You really need a degree from an accredited University program for that discipline.

That being said, for CS, you are probably OK. There are so many jobs that most developers here don't even have a CS degree. One from Ireland might not be as good as one from the top schools here, but there really aren't that many of those folks walking around. I've worked with software engineers who grew up literally around the world (every inhabited continent). Currently my manager is an English national who I believe just went to a small technical school there for a 2-year degree.

Honestly, the only language barrier between us I saw in your message is that "maths" thing. Here "Math" is singular, and "Sports" is plural. We can forgive most of the rest if you keep a bit of your cute accent. :-)

Comment: ha, its far from cute.

but thanks. good too know theres sense overseas

Answer (score -1):

I'm only going to address your language question(s) since the content of a degree isn't relevant.

First, your example of Ireland vs America refers to differences in English language.  Sure, some people will refer to computer science or programming concepts differently depending on where they live, because of local variances in their spoken language.  This can lead to confusion. To some extent this problem exists even in different computer languages.  In Java you have methods.  In C you have functions and procedures.  Are they the same thing?  It's debatable.

Programming languages are, however, the same worldwide for a given instance of the language.  Java is Java no matter where you are.  So if you've learned to program Java in China your skills are applicable to work in Canada.  Some languages have their own variants, but it's not location specific.

I should note that the link you have at the end of the question is merely a question about a specific Java implementation and how it works.  Java, like all computer languages, has different versions and they run on many platforms.  Not all platform+version combinations are possible or usable, and some will have odd bugs or other differences that will surprise you.  The fact that Opera doesn't use a browser plugin like IE and Firefox do is merely an implementation detail in Opera and doesn't really reflect on Java itself (though it does reflect on the usability of Java if you have a lot of Opera-using customers).